# Angular select dropdown empty value doesn't reset to undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why would angular do such a thing?

I just want an empty value that means undefined. When would NULL be useful?

BTW I am using Angular 1.3.14

```
<select ng-model="prFil.category.id" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories">
<option value="prFil.category = undefined">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You use `<option value="">Select</option>` which sets the model to `null`. What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: Well apparently when using the model to filter values in an ng-repeat, null acts as a value so it filters by null which results in no data shown, because it's not undefined. So I added a function on ng-change that checks if the value is null then it make the model undefined again which fixes the issue, but I feel there has to be a better way. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good work finding out what the problem is. It does seem strange that a value of `null` in a `filter` expression is different to `undefined` or an empty string.

In any case, you could have also solved it using this expression

```
... | filter: prFil.category || undefined"
```

Here's a Plunker demo using a slightly modified version of the default `filter` example ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/oYLVJd2IxcsrPXqMwAHj?p=preview

Comment: Naiz, thanks! that's a lot better than that function. Works like a charm even with multiple filters being applied.

Comment: Hey Phil guess what. I broke it again http://plnkr.co/edit/1MPc0BqQGPNIJZ9FRR6z?p=preview

Comment: @Dunctem that's because you're only assigning the `id` to your model

Answer (score 1):

soooo, I still don't know why, but I figured setting a function with ng-change="resetFilter()" that checks if filter is null and makes undefined if null. Here is my code.

```
$scope.filterReset = function(){
  if($scope.prFil.category.id == null){$scope.prFil.category = undefined}
};
```